# Return list with consecutive occurances based on another list

Tags: python, list

I have a list with the following number:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

What I wanna do is count how many consecutive 1s I have and generate a new list like the following one:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1]
```

Is there a way to do it in a more compact way than this method?

```
lst = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
new_lst = []
counter = 0
for i in range(len(lst)):
    if (lst[i] == 1): counter+=1
    else:counter = 0
    new_lst.append(counter)
print(new_lst)
```

Comment: Using walrus operator in list comprehension: `cntr = 0`, `[cntr := cntr + 1 if i == 1 else 0 for i in lst]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take advantage of the [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) if you're using python 3.8 or later:

```py
[counter := counter + 1 if v else 0 for v in lst]
```

or perhaps [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate):

```py
[v for v in itertools.accumulate(lst, lambda acc, v:acc + v if v else 0)]
```

In both case the result is:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not so much compact than the question solution but it's more clear:

```
l = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
s = []

occ = 0
for i in l:
    occ = occ+1 if i==1 else 0
    s.append(occ)
print(s)
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1]
```